# Mapping two kind of responses with Alamofire and AlamofireObjectMapper (iOS - swift)

Tags: ios, swift, api, casting, alamofire

So, I'm making an iOS app the search a movie on imdb database (using omdb api) and the user could save the favorites.

To search by imdbTitle the request url is "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=(imdbTitle)&type=movie", if imdbTitle = "arq", for example, the response is:

```
{
Response = True;
Search =     (
            {
        Poster = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxODQ2MzkyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjU3MTE5OTE@._V1_SX300.jpg";
        Title = ARQ;
        Type = movie;
        Year = 2016;
        imdbID = tt5640450;
    },
            {
        Poster = "N/A";
        Title = Arq;
        Type = movie;
        Year = 2011;
        imdbID = tt2141601;
    },
            {
        Poster = "N/A";
        Title = "A.R.Q.";
        Type = movie;
        Year = 2015;
        imdbID = tt3829612;
    }
);
totalResults = 3;
}
```

But for save the movie I have to search by imdbID, url: "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=(imdbID)", if imdbID is the one from the movie searched, imdbID = tt3829612, and the response is:

```
{
Actors = "Robbie Amell, Rachael Taylor, Shaun Benson, Gray Powell";
Awards = "N/A";
BoxOffice = "N/A";
Country = "USA, Canada";
DVD = "16 Sep 2016";
Director = "Tony Elliott";
Genre = "Sci-Fi, Thriller";
Language = English;
Metascore = "N/A";
Plot = "Trapped in a lab and stuck in a time loop, a disoriented couple fends off masked raiders while harboring a new energy source that could save humanity.";
Poster = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxODQ2MzkyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjU3MTE5OTE@._V1_SX300.jpg";
Production = Netflix;
Rated = "N/A";
Ratings =     (
            {
        Source = "Internet Movie Database";
        Value = "6.4/10";
    },
            {
        Source = "Rotten Tomatoes";
        Value = "60%";
    }
);
Released = "16 Sep 2016";
Response = True;
Runtime = "88 min";
Title = ARQ;
Type = movie;
Website = "N/A";
Writer = "Tony Elliott";
Year = 2016;
imdbID = tt5640450;
imdbRating = "6.4";
imdbVotes = "17,481";
}
```

So, my Movie class has to have the following attributes: poster, title, runtime, genre, director, actors, plot, released, imdbID and imdbRating (to show this on my UI View, except the imdbID, of course)

I'm a beginner and I'm too confused by all those things (never worked with API data before).

Anyways, after a lot of search I found that there is a way to get this response as an Array using AlamofireObjectMapper.

I already have my request functions:

```
func searchMoviesOnJson(imdbTitle: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Dictionary<String, Any>?) -> ()) {

let urlByName: String = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=\(imdbTitle)&type=movie"

//returns a list of movies that contains the title searched
//------------------------------------------------

Alamofire.request(urlByName).responseJSON {
    response in

    switch response.result {

    case .success(let value):
        let moviesJSON = value
        completionHandler(moviesJSON as? Dictionary<String, Any>)

    case .failure(_):
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------

}
func getMovieFromJson(imdbID: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Dictionary<String, String>) -> ()) {

let urlById: String = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=\(imdbID)"

//returns a single movie information
//------------------------------------------------
Alamofire.request(urlById).responseJSON {
    response in

    if let moviesJSON = response.result.value {
        completionHandler(moviesJSON as! Dictionary<String, String>)
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------
}
```

So, could anyone explain to me (like you'll explain to a child) how can I do this mapping? I created a Movie.swift and in this file I'll put my class Movie and class MovieDAO.

How can I implement this two classes using AlamofireObjectMapper and who I have to change in my request methods?

### Update:

```
class Movie {

let poster: String?
let title: String?
let runtime: String?
let genre: String?
let director: String?
let actors: String?
let plot: String?
let released: String?
let imdbID: String?
let imdbRating: String?


init(poster: String?, title: String?, runtime: String?, genre: String?, director: String?, actors: String?, plot: String?, released: String?, imdbID: String?, imdbRating: String?) {

    //checking if is nil

    if let isPoster = poster {
        self.poster = isPoster
    } else {
        self.poster = nil
    }

    if let isTitle = title {
        self.title = isTitle
    } else {
        self.title = nil
    }

    if let isGenre = genre {
        self.genre = isGenre
    } else {
        self.genre = nil
    }

    if let isRuntime = runtime {
        self.runtime = isRuntime
    } else {
        self.runtime = nil
    }

    if let isDirector = director {
        self.director = isDirector
    } else {
        self.director = nil
    }

    if let isActors = actors {
        self.actors = isActors
    } else {
        self.actors = nil
    }

    if let isPlot = plot {
        self.plot = isPlot
    } else {
        self.plot = nil
    }

    if let isReleased = released {
        self.released = isReleased
    } else {
        self.released = nil
    }

    if let isImdbID = imdbID {
        self.imdbID = isImdbID
    } else {
        self.imdbID = nil
    }

    if let isImdbRating = imdbRating {
        self.imdbRating = isImdbRating
    } else {
        self.imdbRating = nil
    }
}
}
```

### UPDATE 2

I declare the variable movieDetail as you said to do, but the xcode showed an error and suggesting that I could add the parameters, so I did and its not solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse the JSON received: 
For e.g. if json received is:

```
{
Response = True;
Search =     (
            {
        Poster = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxODQ2MzkyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjU3MTE5OTE@._V1_SX300.jpg";
        Title = ARQ;
        Type = movie;
        Year = 2016;
        imdbID = tt5640450;
    },
            {
        Poster = "N/A";
        Title = Arq;
        Type = movie;
        Year = 2011;
        imdbID = tt2141601;
    },
            {
        Poster = "N/A";
        Title = "A.R.Q.";
        Type = movie;
        Year = 2015;
        imdbID = tt3829612;
    }
);
totalResults = 3;
}
```

As you have mentioned, if you have stored the json response in NSDictionary

You can access the values of Search results as

```
var moviesArray = [Movie]() //array of your Movie class

var imdbIdArray = [String]()


if let searchResults = moviesJSON["Search"] as? NSArray {
    for searchResult in searchResults {
      let movieResult = searchResult as! Dictionary<String,String>
      let movieDetail = Movie()
      movieDetail.title = movieResult["Title"]
      movieDetail.type = movieResult["Type"] 
    //similarly you can do it for other params as well
      moviesArray.append(movieDetail)
      let imdbId = movieResult["imdbId"]
      imdbIdArray.append(imdbId)
    }

}

class Movie: NSObject {
    var title = String()
    var type = String()
}
```

Now moviesArray consist of list of movies returned in the result set.

Comment: let movieDetail = Movie() what is this "Movie()"?

Comment: Movie is your model class.

Comment: Class Movie : NSObject  { var title = String?  var type = String?}

Comment: Ok, I aked that because there is an error in this line. I updated my question to show the error. Could you please tell me why is that?

Comment: Check the updated answer. I type movieType in place of movieDetail by mistake. Please make the changes.

Comment: I thought you have already create Movie class because you mentioned "my Movie class has to have the following attributes: poster, title, runtime, genre, director, actors, plot, released, imdbID and imdbRating (to show this on my UI View, except the imdbID, of course)"

Comment: Oh Ok, I understand. So, I only need the imdb value, because I need to get the other response (searching by imdbID), so I could have all the attributes of my movie. How can I do that?

Comment: So you mean you want to store imdb id from the array result of movies and then get movies from imdb id  using the function which takes imdb id to get the movie details?

Comment: Added an array of imdbId which stores all the imdbId's retired in the result set.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Hey Mukul, I still dont know how to fix this. Any ideia with those 2 errors? (image uploaded in question update)

Comment: Remove the init code for now.  You are initiliasing it with Params so you cannot create an object without passing those Params.